# Python 2.6 File exists errno 17,

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, error-handling, path

If a file already exists how do I get rid of the error 17 and make a warning message instead?

```
import os, sys

# Path to be created
path = "/tmp/home/monthly/daily"

try:
   os.makedirs(path)
except OSError as e:
  if e.errno == 17:
     //do something

os.makedirs( path, 0755 );

print "Path is created"
```

However it still shows the ERRNO 17 message. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the first call to the `os.makedirs` the directory will be created. (or no change if the directory was already there)

The second call will always raise the exception.

Remove the second call to the `makedirs`:

```
try:
    os.makedirs(path, 0755)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno == 17:  # errno.EEXIST
        os.chmod(path, 0755)

# os.makedirs( path, 0755 )  <----
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable to see if you created the file 
successfully like this:

```
import os, sys

# Path to be created
path = "/tmp/home/monthly/daily"

created = False
is_error_17 = False

try:
   os.makedirs(path)
   created = True
except OSError as e:
  if e.errno == 17:
     print 'File has benn created before'
     is_error_17 = True
     pass

if created == True:
   print 'created file successfully'
else:
   print 'created file failed.'
   if is_error_17 == True:
      print 'you got error 17'
```

In your code if first try catch the error, the second os.makedirs( path, 0755 ); will still raise the error again.

Answer (score 0):

I think does what you want. When an `OSError` error occurs, it checks the error code and prints a warning message if it the one you're interested in handling, otherwise it just propagates the exception. Note the use the optional *mode* argument to `os.makedirs()` which overrides the default of `0777`.

```
import errno, os, sys

# Path to be created
path = "/tmp/home/monthly/daily"

try:
    os.makedirs(path, 0755)
except OSError as e:
    if e.error == errno.EEXIST:  # file exists error?
        print 'warning: {} exists'.format(path)
    else:
        raise  # re-raise the exception

# make sure its mode is right
os.chmod(path, 0755)

print "Path existed or was created"
```