# Create multiple folders if it does not exist using python

Tags: python

I have several xml files(more than 20000) present in one directory. I need to get the application folder name from each xml file then move the file to its respective application folder (application name can be same for two files).

With `"if not os.path.exists('Working_Dir/app'):"` I am trying to check for each application if it is present or not. With next line I am trying to create that folder but somehow it is not checking for folder existence.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys, glob

Working_Dir = "/home"
path1 = "/home/xmlFiles"
path2 = "/home/JobFolder"

if not os.path.exists(path1):
    os.mkdir(path1, 0755);

if not os.path.exists(path2):
    os.mkdir(path2, 0755);

for files in glob.glob("*.xml"):
    f = open( files)
    for line in f:
        if "ParentApplication" in line:
            app = line.split('.')[1]
            if not os.path.exists('Working_Dir/app'):
                os.makedirs(app)
```

Below is the error which i am getting.

```
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    os.mkdir(app, 0755);
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'TRC'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this links maybe help you.

1. [python-2-6-file-exists-errno-17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978889/python-2-6-file-exists-errno-17)
2. [python-fileexists-error-when-making-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468022/python-fileexists-error-when-making-directory)

I think what you do is just to raise the exception.I can not reappear your Exception.

Comment: Thanks, It is working after keeping this error as exception.

Comment: After creating folder i tried to move the file to respective folder but that is throwing error. 
if "ParentApplication" in line:
   app = line.split('.')[1]
   try:
    os.makedirs(app, 0755)
   except OSError as exception:
    if exception.errno != 17:
     raise
   shutil.move('Working_Dir/f.name', 'Working_Dir/app')

Below is the error:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Working_Dir/f.name'

Answer (score 0):

`shutil.move('Working_Dir/f.name', 'Working_Dir/app')` Is this correct?
I think it is trying to search `f.name` in the working directory.
See if this helps:

```
import os, sys, glob, errno, shutil`

Working_Dir = "/home"
path1 = "/home/xmlFiles"
path2 = "/home/JobFolder"

if not os.path.exists(path1):
os.mkdir(path1, 0755);

if not os.path.exists(path2):
os.mkdir(path2, 0755);

for files in glob.glob("*.py"):
 f = open( files)
 for line in f:
    if "test." in line:
        app = line.split('.')[1]
        print app
        try:
            print app
            os.makedirs(Working_Dir+'/'+app, 0755)
        except OSError as exception:
            if exception.errno != 17:
                raise
        s=Working_Dir+'/'+f.name
        t=Working_Dir+'/'+app+'/'
        shutil.move(s, t)
```